# Fundamental group of Topologists sine curve

Tags: fundamental-groups

How can one prove that the fundamental group of the topologists sine curve is trivial? I haven't been able to make any progress on this. A hint in the right direction preferred over a complete solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing you have the parametrization of the curve given [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topologist%27s_sine_curve), try to show that any curve with base point $(0,0)$ has to be constant.

Then show that any curve with basepoint not at $(0,0)$ cannot pass through $(0,0)$, and use the fact that the topologist sine curve without $(0,0)$ is homeomorphic to the real line.

Comment: So I have managed with the first part, and I believe with the second part -  I showed the topologist sine curve without (0,0) is homeomorphic to [ 1, ∞ ), which is contractible and therefore has a trivial fundamental group. Is this correct? (You stated that that the topologist sine curve without (0,0) is homeomorphic to the real line, which I couldn't see -- but showing is homeomorphic to [ 1, ∞ ) seemed to do the trick). Your hint was very helpful, thank you.

Comment: @qwert4321 : I don't see how you've shown this, because it's not what you want. The homeomorphism is simply given by $(x, \sin(1/x)) \mapsto x$, so that the topologist sine curve is homeomorphic to $]0,\infty[$, which is homeomorphic to the real line (but if I told you it was homeomorphic to $]0,\infty[$, it would have been kind of a bigger hint!). But the contractible part and the rest of your argument is fine!